# Creating a call function for multiple classes

Tags: python, class, call, multiple-inheritance

So I got my code to work, but two lines are messing me up, and not quite sure what to put.

Code(the two lines are marked):

```
class Person(object):
    numPerson = 0
    def __init__(self,firstName,lastName):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    def fullName(self):
        print self.firstName +' '+self.lastName

class Employee(Person):
    numEmployee = 0
    def __init__(self,firstName,lastName,pay,employID):
        Person.__init__(self, firstName, lastName)
        self.pay = pay
        self.employID = employID
        Employee.numEmployee += 1

class Programmer(Employee):
    def __init__(self,firstName,lastName,pay,employID,proLang):
        self.proLang = proLang
        Employee.__init__(self, firstName, lastName, pay, employID)

class Manager(Employee):
    def __init__(self,firstName,lastName,pay,employID,progList):
        self.progList = progList
        Employee.__init__(self, firstName, lastName, pay, employID)
    def addProgrammer(self):
        self.progList.append(Programmer.fullName) <------------------- This line
    def removeProgrammer(self):
        if len(self.progList) == 0:
            pass
        else:
            del self.progList[0]
    def printList(self):
        print self.progList

a = Manager('Alfred','Jones',20.00,0001,[])
b = Programmer('James','Smith', 11.75, 0002, 'Java')
a.addProgrammer() <--------------------------------------------- And This line
a.printList()
```

I'm trying to add the programmer's name to the `progList` using the `.addProgramer` method. I keep trying different combos and this is the closest I got.

Output:

```
[<unbound method Programmer.fullName>]
```

So, I'm not sure what needs to be in the `addProgramer` method in order to properly add the programmers name, or if I need an argument inside the `a.addProgrammer` at the very end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
self.progList.append(Programmer.fullName)
```

You're not adding an instance of a programmer, you are adding a method from the programmer class.

Also:

```
def fullName(self):
    print self.firstName +' '+self.lastName
```

This doesn't actually return the name of the programmer, it only prints it to the console. To actually output and use the the fullname you need to `return self.firstName + ' ' + self.lastName`

Likewise in that function you also need to specify which programmer you are adding:

```
def addProgrammer(self, added_programmer):
    self.progList.append(added_programmer.fullName()) # Call the function to get the fullname
```

And now to add a programmer:

```
Alfred = Manager('Alfred','Jones',20.00,0001,[]) #make a manager     
James = Programmer('James','Smith', 11.75, 0002, 'Java') #make a programmer
Alfred.addProgrammer(James) #add the programmer
Alfred.printList()
```

Putting this all together:

```
class Person(object):
    numPerson = 0
    def __init__(self,firstName,lastName):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    def fullName(self):
        return self.firstName +' '+self.lastName

class Employee(Person):
    numEmployee = 0
    def __init__(self,firstName,lastName,pay,employID):
        Person.__init__(self, firstName, lastName)
        self.pay = pay
        self.employID = employID
        Employee.numEmployee += 1

class Programmer(Employee):
    def __init__(self,firstName,lastName,pay,employID,proLang):
        self.proLang = proLang
        Employee.__init__(self, firstName, lastName, pay, employID)

class Manager(Employee):
    def __init__(self,firstName,lastName,pay,employID,progList):
        self.progList = progList
        Employee.__init__(self, firstName, lastName, pay, employID)
    def addProgrammer(self, added_programmer):
        self.progList.append(added_programmer.fullName()) # Call the function to get the fullname
    def removeProgrammer(self):
        if len(self.progList) == 0:
            pass
        else:
            del self.progList[0]
    def printList(self):
        print self.progList

Alfred = Manager('Alfred','Jones',20.00,1,[])       
James = Programmer('James','Smith', 11.75, 2, 'Java')
Alfred.addProgrammer(James)
Alfred.printList()
```

Comment: I'm happy to help! If my solution solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it. Thanks :)